# Autofac define method injection in xml configuration

Tags: c#, xml, autofac

I'm using Autofac xml configuration file to register some classes, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <autofac defaultAssembly="ChainOfResponsibilities">
   <components name="0">
    <type>ChainOfResponsibilities.ClassA, ChainOfResponsibilities</type>
    <services name="0" type="ChainOfResponsibilities.IClassA" />
    <InstanceScope>perlifetimescope</InstanceScope>
    <injectProperties>true</injectProperties>
   </components>
  </autofac>
```

Now, I want to inject this class to a method inside another class that is also registered in the same xml configuration file. In other words i'm trying to achieve the same result of the following code using the xml configuration file

```
 builder.Register(c =>
        {
            var chainManager = new ChainManager();
            var chainList = new List<Chain> { new Chain(c.Resolve<IClassA>)};
            chainManager.AddChain(chainList);
            return chainManager;
        });
```

I thought about using property injection or metadata but had no luck getting the result i wanted.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configuration mechanism is handy, but it isn't meant to be feature-for-feature compatible with the flexibility of code.

It doesn't support method injection, lambda registrations, or lifetime event handlers which would be necessary to get a method like `AddChain` from your example called.

You will probably have to keep code around to do the method injection and only put the "chain" items in configuration.